# modeling of a dc motor with load

Tags: identification, control, motor-controller, modeling, actuator

I designed a robot. It consists of an actuator, linkage and a camera. the actuator is considered as a dc motor in this problem. I need to identify this system. how can I find a model for actuator and loads on it(camera and linkage have mass)?

I used this actuator

[image]

[image]

edited: 
It is a 2 Dof robot. camera rotates about y and movies up and down (z-axis). The camera and linkage are attached to the Stroke. When the camera is lifting up, the actuator is retracting and when it moves down, the actuator is expanding.

Comment: Does that actuator have a **data sheet** or a **part number**?  I suspect that the actuator is so heavily geared down that your system dynamics will only be affected if the static load on the actuator changes (i.e., if you're lifting the camera for part of the stroke and lowering it for another, or if you've got a multi-axis robot that can change the direction of force exerted on the actuator).

Comment: @TimWescott, It is a 2 Dof robot. camera rotates about y and movies up and down (z-axis). The camera and linkage are attached to the Stroke. When the camera is lifting up, the actuator is retracting and when it moves down, the actuator is expanding.

Comment: determin the masses involved you can model the static and dynamic loads,

Answer (score 1):

Determine the masses involved and the geometry of the system and you can model the static and dynamic loads.

It would take a mammoth effort to get the voltage and current needed to slew the camera at such and such rate by modeling. But you should be able to determine if you are within the limits set out for the strength of the actuator and the hinge etc.

Comment: could you please provide some materials that I can read to understand the process of modeling. It is my first time that I am going to model this kinda system. you referred to static and dynamic loads, I really did not get what are static and dynamic loads.

Comment: Start with Archimede's principle of the lever.

Comment: I am familiar with the Archimedes principle of the lever.  could you pls explain what would be the steps for modeling this system?

Comment: there's friction and weight, your actuator must overcome those innertia too if you're in a hurry.

Comment: how should I find the inertia and friction?

Comment: Hire a physics undergrad.